# How can i pair and unpair the bluetooth sensortag with a 4.4 android device?

Tags: android, listview, bluetooth

How to pair and unpair a Bluetooth sensortag with an Android 4.4 device?

When I search for the sensortag I can discover it, but I need to connect it with my Android device.

My layout file is:

```
 <Button
          android:id="@+id/paired"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Pair" />

       <Button
          android:id="@+id/search"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Search new devices" />

       <ListView
           android:id="@+id/listView1"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="200dp" >

       </ListView>
```

And my Java code is:

```
findBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.search);
          findBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            find(v);
        }
      });



      public void find(View view) {
       if (myBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
           // the button is pressed when it discovers, so cancel the discovery
           myBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
       }
       else {
            BTArrayAdapter.clear();
            myBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();

            registerReceiver(bReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));    
        }    
   }
```

I need to include the pairing of sensorTag in the method:

```
public void pair(View v){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sensortag is a Bluetooth Low energy device so you need to have knowledge of how it works.

Read the developer docs [**Here**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html). there are various examples with code given on the page try some of that and get back with some progress.The code you have written isn't going to get you anywhere.

To Pair and Unpair the simple steps would be

1. Setting Up BLE
2. Finding BLE Devices
3. Then Connect to BLE device